# Error 400 : PHP 5.4 applications are prevented from being deployed to Google App Engine

Tags: php, google-app-engine

This is my `app.yaml` file:

```
application: xxxxxxxxxxxxx
version: 1
runtime: php55
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:

- url: /images
  static_dir: images

- url: /css
  static_dir: css

- url: /js
  static_dir: js

- url: /libraries
  static_dir: libraries

- url: /
  script: main.php

# Serve php scripts.
- url: /(.+\.php)$
  script: \1
```

This is the error I get:

> Error 400: --- begin server output ---
>
> PHP 5.4 applications are prevented from being deployed to Google App Engine from any version of the SDK, including older ones. If you need to continue to deploy PHP 5.4 applications for compatibility reasons, you can request that your application be whitelisted for PHP 5.4 deployment by visiting http://goo.gl/qjKEuk.
>
> --- end server output ---

Can somebody please tell me why I still get this error after changing `runtime` from `php` to `php55` in `app.yaml`?

Comment: have you tried increasing the version number?

Comment: How are you pushing your app, are you using appcfg.py or some IDE like PhpStorm or something else?

Comment: i'm using php storm. i updated the sdk too still no luck

Comment: increased the version number still not working

Comment: Have you tried deploying via command line, i.e.: `appcfg.py update <PATH_TO_YOUR_PROJECT> --oauth2` ?

Comment: it worked through command line. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PhpStorm plugin is still not compatible with deploying php55 apps. Deploying through Google App Engine Launcher works fine.

Comment: that was the case for me

Answer (score 3):

You need to update your Google App Engine Launcher to 1.9.18 or higher.  You can't use php55 with 1.9.17 (and I just updated to 1.9.20 and it is a bit different, uses your browser to log in).